# Using for loops to perform mathematical operations on data frames

Tags: r

I have a data frame "DEM2" consisting 160 rows and 12 columns and I want to create a new data frame  "zcp_DEM" fulfilling

```
     zcb_DEM[1,i] <- 100/(100+DEM2[i,2]) ## for all i in 1:160
     ## for all i in 1:160 and j in 2:11
     zcb_DEM[j,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,j])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:j-1,i])*(DEM2[i,j]/100))
```

My idea was to use one or two for loops. So far, I wrote the following code which unfortunately doesn't seem to be working:

```
    zcb_DEM <- matrix(nrow = 11, ncol = 160)
    for (i in 1:160 ) {

    zcb_DEM[1,i] <- 100/(100+DEM2[i,2])
    zcb_DEM[2,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,2])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:1,i])*(DEM2[i,2]/100)) 
    zcb_DEM[3,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,3])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:2,i])*(DEM2[i,3]/100))
    zcb_DEM[4,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,4])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:3,i])*(DEM2[i,4]/100))
    zcb_DEM[5,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,5])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:4,i])*(DEM2[i,5]/100))
    zcb_DEM[6,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,6])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:5,i])*(DEM2[i,6]/100))
    zcb_DEM[7,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,7])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:6,i])*(DEM2[i,7]/100))
    zcb_DEM[8,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,8])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:7,i])*(DEM2[i,8]/100))
    zcb_DEM[9,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,9])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:8,i])*(DEM2[i,9]/100))
    zcb_DEM[10,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,10])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:9,i])*(DEM2[i,10]/100))
    zcb_DEM[11,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,11])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:10,i])*(DEM2[i,11]/100))
    print(zcb_DEM)

 }
```

Or more elegantly

```
    for (i in 1:160) {
     for (j in 2:11) {
      zcb_DEM[1,i] <- 100/(100+DEM2[i,2])
      zcb_DEM[j,i] <- (100/100+DEM2[i,j])*(1-sum(zcb_DEM[1:j-1,i])*(DEM2[i,j]/100))
       print(zcb_DEM)
      }}
```

which doesn't work either.

**EDIT**   When running the first code I obtain the following:

```
        [,155] [,156] [,157] [,158] [,159] [,160] ##this is the last block appearing in the console
 [1,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   ##for each row there is such a NA vector appearing
 [2,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [3,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [4,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [5,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [6,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [7,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [8,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [9,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [10,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [11,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

When using `warnings()` the following (errors) appears

```
    Warnmeldungen:
 1: In Ops.factor(100, DEM2[i, 2]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
 2: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 2]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
 3: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 2], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
 4: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 3]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
 5: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 3], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
 6: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 4]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
 7: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 4], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
 8: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 5]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
 9: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 5], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
10: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 6]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
11: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 6], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
12: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 7]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
13: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 7], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
14: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 8]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
15: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 8], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
16: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 9]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
17: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 9], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
18: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 10]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
19: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 10], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
20: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 11]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
21: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 11], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
22: In Ops.factor(100, DEM2[i, 2]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
23: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 2]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
24: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 2], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
25: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 3]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
26: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 3], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
27: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 4]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
28: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 4], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
29: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 5]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
30: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 5], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
31: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 6]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
32: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 6], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
33: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 7]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
34: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 7], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
35: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 8]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
36: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 8], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
37: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 9]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
38: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 9], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
39: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 10]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
40: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 10], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
41: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 11]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
42: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 11], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
43: In Ops.factor(100, DEM2[i, 2]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
44: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 2]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
45: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 2], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
46: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 3]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
47: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 3], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
48: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 4]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
49: In Ops.factor(DEM2[i, 4], 100) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
50: In Ops.factor(100/100, DEM2[i, 5]) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

**EDIT²** I found where my error was: the data frame DEM2 wasn't completely numerical, I just had to fix it.

Comment: Please don't use the RStudio tag unless your problem is about the code editor RStudio. You wouldn't use a `Microsoft Word` tag for a grammar question even if you happened to be using it to write English, and you shouldn't use the `RStudio` tag only because you are using that program (rather than emacs, Vim, Notepad, RGui, or anything else) to write your R code.

Comment: for the first line use `zcb_DEM[1,] <- 100/(100+DEM2[,2])`

Comment: for the second line, have a look at `?purrr::accumulate`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not specific. Error? Or unexpected result? Second line semantic (but not syntactic ) error, so perhaps no error message. When using indices such as `[1:j-1,i]`, you should always, always use parentheses. The operator precedence has `":"` higher than the binary minus sign. See `?Syntax`

Comment: This looks like you are transposing with a mathematical equation which includes a running sum. There may be a different approach without any `for` loop. But please tell us what *doesn't work* or better show us with current and desired data output.

Comment: Alright @HubertL thanks. I will have a look at at `?purrr::accumulate`
As for the Error, I will edit my question and be more precise.